# Why does 日本語{にほんご} mean Japanese?

Tags: words, meaning

Google translate says 日本語 means Japanese.

It also says:

- 語 means "word"
- 本 means "this"
- 日 means "day"

So how do you get "Japanese" out of these three kanji?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- 語 is the suffix which means 'language'. Unlike English which needs two different nouns for a country and its language, in Japanese, you can simply add 語 after the name of a country to mean the language spoken in that country. (e.g. ドイツ = Germany, ドイツ語 = German, フランス = France, フランス語 = French)
- 日本 is one word made of two characters, meaning 'Japan'. Etymologically [it can be further analyzed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_Japan#Nihon_and_Nippon) (日 (Sun) + 本 (origin) => the rising Sun), but no one cares about that in everyday life.

Comment: By the way, 本日, pronounced *honjitsu*, actually means 'this day', or 'today'.

Answer (score 4):

- 日 Can also mean "Sun"
- 本 Can mean "Origin"
- 語 Can mean "language"

If you look at the Japanese Flag ,you will notice there is a big red circle. That is a sun. The sun is a very important object in Japanese folklore.
Another thing is that 日本語 refers to the Japanese language which we often just refer to as Japanese